# Return additional column in Linq Query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have this Linq query:

```
var area = db.MyDbSet
    .Where(s => s.langid == langid)
    .GroupBy(s => s.Title)
    .Select(g => new { Title = g.Key })
    .Select(s => s.Title);
```

I want to return another column from the same table, its called: `CodeId`.

I am noob Linq programmer and quite lost in all those mish-mash things in C# so I can't really understand what should I do.

Can somebody help me how to return the another column from the same table with the same query call?

Comment: Just add the column in the query like this: `.Select(g => new { Title = g.Key , CodeId = g.propertyName})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help you :

```
 var area = db.MyDbSet
                    .Where(s => s.langid == langid)
                    .GroupBy(s => s.Title)
                    .Select(g => new { Title = g.Key, CodeId = g.FirstOrDefault().CodeId });
```

Comment: What would FirstOrDefault do? Take just one value? But i don't see CodeId in the next line when I type s.CodeId. It doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Here query will group data by Title and after groupby the first CodeId of that group will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
var area = db.MyDbSet
    .Where(s => s.langid == langid)
    .GroupBy(s => s.Title)
    .Select(g => new { 
      Title = g.Key,
      CodeId = g.Id,
      OtherField = "Field"
    })
```

Comment: Turns out I have a problem with my model, so g.CodeId is not visible.

Comment: I have two keys in this table, langid and CodeId, so they are marked with [Key, Column(Order = 0)] and [Key, Column(Order = 1)] Should do something additional in my query, or the problem is in my model?